# How can i send api request through python for mirrorace.org

Tags: python, php, api

I want to upload files in mirrorace but i cant understand their api they have given an example php code but i cant understand it.Can somebody tell me how can i make a post request from python
This is their api documentation https://mirrorace.org/api
Please someone help me I am new to python.

Comment: Welcome, cool movies! (I love movies.) Unfortunately this is a really generic question and StackOverflow isn't necessarily the best place for these. [Read about what's on-topic here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You may want to reach out to Mirror Ace for support, find a message board or chat group that can help, or other resources. Best wishes.

Comment: What have you tried already? Did you read the docs? If so, why don't you mention which type of upload you plan to use, File Direct or File Remote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check out the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library if I were you.

Here are some other resources you can check out:

- [W3- Python Requests post() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp)
- [requests - POST Multipart Encoded Files](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files)
- [RealPython Lesson](https://realpython.com/api-integration-in-python/)

Of course, there are plenty of other API libraries you'll be able to find being used. I'd recommend staying as far away as you can from anything having "async" support. Async is relatively new to python, and while I use it plenty, it certainly would be a baptism-by-fire kind of scenario for someone just starting out with the language.

Answer (score 0):

First time I heard about *mirrorace.org*, so I coded this in a couple of minutes specially for this question, despite that, it does work with the default mirrors:

```
from requests import Session
import mimetypes
from pathlib import Path

def get_mime(f):
    return mimetypes.guess_type(f)[0]

s = Session()

api_key = "xxx"
api_token = "xxx"
req1_url = "https://mirrorace.com/api/v1/file/upload" # get info needed for req2

data = {"api_key": api_key, "api_token": api_token}
req1 = s.post(req1_url, data=data).json()
if req1['status'] == 'success':
    upload_key = req1['result']['upload_key']
    cTracker = req1['result']['cTracker']
    server_file = req1['result']['server_file']
    max_mirrors = req1['result']['max_mirrors'] # max mirror allowed to upload
    mirrors = list([k for k, v in req1['result']['mirrors'].items() if v])[:int(max_mirrors)] # create a list of enabled mirror id's with cap based on max_mirrors

    if upload_key and cTracker and server_file and mirrors:
        f = "C:/Users/0x/Desktop/A CARNE (letra e vídeo) com SEU JORGE, vídeo MOACIR SILVEIRA (320 kbps).mp3"
        fn = Path(f).name
        print("FILE NAME:", fn)
        mime_type = get_mime(f)
        print("MIME TYPE:", mime_type)

        # file = {"files": open(f,'rb')} # also works
        file = {'files': (fn, open(f,'rb'), mime_type)}
        # file = {'files': ("new_filename.mp3", open(f,'rb'), mime_type)}  # also works
        
        data = {"api_key": api_key, "api_token": api_token, "cTracker": cTracker, "upload_key": upload_key, "mirrors[]": mirrors}
        req2 = s.post(server_file, files=file, data=data).json()
        if req2['status'] == 'success':
            # {'status': 'success', 'result': {'name': 'A CARNE (letra e vídeo) com SEU JORGE, vídeo MOACIR SILVEIRA (320 kbps).mp3', 'size': 11929965, 'slug': '3Jcad', 'url': 'https://mirrorace.org/m/3Jcad', 'info': 'complete'}}
            print(req2['result']['url'])
        else:
            print("Error: ", req2)
    else:
        print("Error data missing: ",  upload_key, cTracker, server_file, mirrors)
else:
    print("Error: ", req1)
```

---

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/x011/7163744ed2ed38a775b9b99c1dfd7260)